AppleScript Automation for Capture One 21: trouble with script for monitoring a folder
I’m hoping someone can assist me with an automation issue I’ve been working on for the photo software "Capture One 21“. I need a folder (the capture folder on my desktop) to be monitored, and whenever a new file is added to it, the program (Capture One) should trigger the Command+D keyboard shortcut to export the RAW file into a JPG file. The JPG file ends in an other folder after exported.
Unfortunately, I have no background in programming, so I spent many hours trying to create a script with the help of ChatGPT, but now I’m just going around in circles.
So, what I’m basically trying to achieve:

I want Capture One to automatically execute the "Command+D" keyboard shortcut every time a new image appears in my tethered capture folder on my desktop called "Hochzeit Teather Ordner".

What I’ve done so far:

Automator workflow:

I’ve set up an Automator workflow that monitors the "Hochzeit Teather Ordner".
The workflow includes a shell script that checks for new files in the folder.
When a change is detected, an AppleScript is supposed to send the "Command+D" keyboard shortcut to Capture One.


Shell script in Automator:

The shell script saves a list of files in the folder and periodically checks for updates.
If a new file is detected, it triggers the AppleScript to simulate the keyboard shortcut.


AppleScript for sending keystrokes:

The AppleScript is intended to send the "Command+D" shortcut to Capture One whenever a new image is detected.
Unfortunately, I keep encountering a syntax error: "end expected, but on found."
Despite several attempts to troubleshoot, this issue persists, and I can't seem to get the script to work correctly.



Problems encountered:

Syntax errors: Repeatedly encountering the "end expected, but on found" error in the AppleScript.
Automation permissions: Ensuring that Automator and System Events have the necessary permissions to send keystrokes, but still running into issues.
Script execution: Despite several revisions, the AppleScript fails to execute as expected.

What I need help with:

Fixing the AppleScript syntax error and ensuring it works seamlessly with the Automator workflow.
Any advice or alternative approaches to achieve the desired automation in Capture One 21.
Clarification on any specific permissions or settings that might be affecting the workflow.

Current shell script:
#!/bin/bash
captureFolder="$1"tempFile="/tmp/current_files.txt"

Save initial file list
ls "$captureFolder" > "$tempFile" 

New file monitoring loop
while true; dosleep 10 currentFiles=$(ls "$captureFolder")if ! diff <(echo "$currentFiles") "$tempFile" > /dev/null; thenosascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "d" using {command down}'ls "$captureFolder" > "$tempFile"fidone

Current AppleScript:
on run {input, parameters} -- Pfad zum Capture One-Ordner
set captureFolderPath to POSIX path of (item 1 of input)

-- Helper function to retrieve the file names in the folder
-- on listFilesInFolder(folderPath)
--    set fileList to do shell script "ls " & quoted form of folderPath
--    return fileList
-- end listFilesInFolder

-- Save initial file list
set currentFiles to listFilesInFolder(captureFolderPath)

-- New file monitoring loop
repeat
    delay 10 -- Warte 10 Sekunden
    
    -- Get new file list
    set newFiles to listFilesInFolder(captureFolderPath)
    
    -- Check if the file list has changed
    if currentFiles ≠ newFiles then
        -- Wenn sich die Dateiliste geändert hat, sende Tastenkombination an Capture One
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Capture One 21" -- Ersetze "Capture One 21" durch die Version, die du verwendest
                if exists window 1 then
                    keystroke "d" using {command down}
                end if
            end tell
        end tell
        
        -- Update the list of current files
        set currentFiles to newFiles
    end if
end repeat

return input
end run

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

The AppleScript error occurs because any handler (on …) must be on the top level of the script.
And there is another major problem. Keystrokes are sent always to the frontmost application, so you have to activate Capture One before sending the keystroke. I'm surprised how stupid ChatGPT is .
on run {input, parameters} -- Pfad zum Capture One-Ordner
    set captureFolderPath to POSIX path of (item 1 of input)
    
    -- Save initial file list
    set currentFiles to listFilesInFolder(captureFolderPath)
    
    -- New file monitoring loop
    repeat
        delay 10 -- Warte 10 Sekunden
        
        -- Get new file list
        set newFiles to listFilesInFolder(captureFolderPath)
        
        -- Check if the file list has changed
        if currentFiles ≠ newFiles then
            -- Wenn sich die Dateiliste geändert hat, sende Tastenkombination an Capture One
            activate application "Capture One 21" -- ⚠️ this line is mandatory
            tell application "System Events"
                tell process "Capture One 21" -- Ersetze "Capture One 21" durch die Version, die du verwendest
                    if exists window 1 then
                        keystroke "d" using {command down}
                    end if
                end tell
            end tell
            
            -- Update the list of current files
            set currentFiles to newFiles
        end if
    end repeat
    
    return input
end run

-- Helper function to retrieve the file names in the folder
on listFilesInFolder(folderPath)
    set fileList to do shell script "ls " & quoted form of folderPath
    return fileList
end listFilesInFolder

However checking the folder periodically for file changes is very expensive and an awful practice.
AppleScript provides Folder Actions which can monitor a folder reacting to AppleEvents. Put this script into ~/Library/Scripts (~ is the home folder) and setup Folder Actions in Finder by right-click on the folder > Services > Folder Action Setup…
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    activate application "Capture One 21"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Capture One 21"
            if exists window 1 then
                keystroke "d" using {command down}
            end if
        end tell
    end tell
end adding folder items to

Regarding the permissions you have to give Script Editor permission for Accessibility in System Settings > Private & Security > Accessibility.
A last note: Is there a menu item which triggers the keystroke in `Capture One?. If yes use that because it doesn't require to bring the target application to the front.
